# Vote buttons in the banner are different from the actual vote buttons

Tags: bug, status-review, design, voting, notification-bar

When you visit a site you haven't joined yet, it shows this banner:

[image]

The current vote buttons don't match with the ones in the banner. Is there a redesign in progress for the banner?

Note: From my point of view, I'd rather have the buttons redesigned to match the buttons in the banner (and it looks like a lot of people would prefer this, too)

Comment: P.S. The banner is not visible on mobile. Only on desktop.

Comment: @RandomPerson The banner becomes visible on mobile when I rotate to landscape mode.

Comment: Do the icons need to match? The icons in the banner are pretty simple and I see them as more like abstract icons to represent voting in general, rather than a 1 to 1 mapping of the site's design. If it was the other way around (we still had the old vote button design and the icons depicted in the banner were the ones with a rounded border), then I would say yes, it needs to be changed to the more simple design (not to match the site, but to have a simple abstract non-opinionated design).

Comment: Well, more important to keep the [tour page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour) up to date, it's much more prominent there and visible to anyone, anywhere, always.