# Vote buttons in the tour page are different from the actual vote buttons

Tags: bug, status-review, design, tour

Essentially the same as this question, [Vote buttons in the banner are different from the actual vote buttons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389859/vote-buttons-in-the-banner-are-different-from-the-actual-vote-buttons), except that this is about the example vote buttons in [the tour page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour); the depicted buttons are not the same as the new ones.

> [image]

Please update the vote buttons picture on the tour page.

Comment: Alternative solution: Please revert the actual vote buttons to the traditional style, as soon as the data confirms that the increase in voting was only a temporary, transient effect caused by them looking different.

Comment: I support this alternative solution. Additionally, the comment voting buttons don't match the new voting style either.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393595/the-established-user-help-page-image-should-be-updated#comment1316233_393595

Comment: Works for me if this bug doesn't get fixed because I dislike the new designs anyway.