# The established-user help page image should be updated

Tags: feature-request, design, privileges, help-center

If you go to the `/help/privileges/established-user` help page on any SE website, you will see this screenshot:

[image: screenshot that is on the established-user privileges help page]

This is quite outdated.  Now that the [vote button is standard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389359/we-are-graduating-the-updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows), this screenshot should be updated to reflect the new buttons, as well as the current text of the vote spread.

Comment: The better solution would be to use clearly visible voting indicators again - maybe this site would then no longer be outdated :)

Comment: We have a ticket in our system to review the current buttons and review feedback about them being difficult to discern the difference between selected and unselected states - I can add a note to that ticket that once we complete the change, we should update documentation like this to show the new voting buttons. While it'd be going the extra mile, if y'all happened to add other places that aren't user-editable where we're using screenshots of the old design, that'd be really helpful.